# Need help using a while statement and getting the math right

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm still very new to coding.  My teacher is very hard to understand so I need online help.  For this, I need to find the value in a savings account after months of compounding interest. I know that my math is wrong but I don't know how to fix this, and I've never written a while statement.  Please help me out.

From my prompt:

> "Suppose you save $100 each month into the savings account and the
>   annual interest rate is 5%.   So, the monthly interest rate is 0.05/12
>   = 0.00417.   After the first month, the value in the account becomes 100* (1 + 0.00417) = $100.417    After the second month, the value in
>   the account becomes (100 + 100.417) * (1 + 0.00417) = $201.252 After
>   the third month, the value in the account becomes
>          (100 + 201.252) * (1 + 0.00417) = $302.507 and so on."

```
double initialSavings;
System.out.print("How much money would you like to save each month? $");
initialSavings = userInput.nextDouble();

double annualInterest;
System.out.print("What is the annual interest rate for your savings account? (Example, 2.5) ");
annualInterest = userInput.nextDouble();

int months;
System.out.print("How many months would you like to keep saving? ");
months = userInput.nextInt();

double monthlyInterest;
monthlyInterest = annualInterest / 12;

int count = 1;

while (count <= months) {

count++;

double result;

result = initialSavings * count * (1 + monthlyInterest);

}

System.out.println("You will have $"+ result "after "+ months "months.");
}
}
```

Comment: If your teacher is hard to understand, make them repeat it. If they're not willing to explain, complain to your learning institution. You're paying for an education, and the teacher is being paid to provide it to you. If they're not doing their job, then your university should be made aware of that fact. That doesn't move the responsibility of teaching you to us, however. *Please help me out* is not a question, an *I know my math is wrong* is not a meaningful problem description.

Comment: @heyimakitty There is a wrong way and a right way to ask questions here.  Never mention that its for homework or work.  Just get straight to the point and ask your question.

Answer (score 2):

`result` should be out of the loop and your `result` value should carry over into each calculation.  This is why the `result` variable is assigned to itself thus compounding your initial investment as well as the additional 100 invested each month.

```
var result = 0.0;
while (count <= months) {
    result = (result + savingsAmount) * (1 + monthlyInterest);
    count++; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need of while to calculate it.
this way you'll get the final ammount of money. You need to get the Interest/100 if you are inserting values like "10" to 10%.

```
result = initialSavings*(1+((monthlyInterest/100)*months))
```

for the compounded interest:

```
result = initialSavings*Math.pow((1+(monthlyInterest/100)),months);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the calculation is wrong.
Second month interest should be calculated with concerning 
 initialSavings + first month interest.

this is a common formula used for interest calculation.

```
A = amount
P = principal
R = monthly rate
n = months

 A=P(1+R)^n
```

try like this

```
  double initialSavings = 100;
  int months= 5;
  double rate = 0.00417;

  System.out.printf("Inital Savings: %.2f \n", initialSavings);
  System.out.println("Months: " + months);
  System.out.println("Monthy Interest rate: " + rate);

  System.out.println("Total amount componded over the " + months+ " months:"     );
  for(int x = 1; x <= months; x++) {
     double amount = initialSavings* Math.pow(1+ rate, x);
     System.out.printf("Month" + x + ": %.2f \n" , amount);
  }
```